# Java Struts 1 Encoding issue

Tags: java, csv, character-encoding, export-to-csv

I'm working on a Struts 1 application (Java 1.8.0_333) for a client, and I have an encoding issue when export CSV data. I'm using WebLogic version 12.1 locally, on this environment. I have no problems with special characters (accents are correctly displayed):

[image: Local display]

But on the testing server of the client, I have a strange encoding problem:

[image: Server display]

I think it's something related to the OS, server run on Linux and my local OS is Windows.

Here is the code of the CSV export:

```java
public ActionForward exporter(final ActionMapping mapping, final ActionForm aForm, final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) throws HibernateException, ServletException, IOException {

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy");
    String filename = "agents" + format.format(new Date()) + ".csv";
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

    final Session session = Persistance.getSession();

    ArrayList<Agents> listAgents = null;
    String q = "FROM Agents agents JOIN FETCH agents.organisation WHERE agents.supprime = '0'  ";

    // export agents actifs
    if ("active".equals(request.getParameter("choix"))) {
        q += " AND statut_agent = '1'";
    }

    // export agents désactivés
    if ("desactive".equals(request.getParameter("choix"))) {
        q += " AND statut_agent = '0'";
    }

    q += " ORDER BY agents.nom, agents.prenom, agents.organisation.label";
    listAgents = (ArrayList<Agents>) session.createQuery(q).list();

    //FileWriter csvWriter = new FileWriter(filename);

    // entêtes
    String csv = "Nom;Prenom;Service;ID_UNITE;Batiment;Actif\n";

    for (Agents agent : listAgents) {
        String organisation = agent.getOrganisation().getLabel() == null ? "" : agent.getOrganisation().getLabel();
        String batiment = agent.getBatiment() == null ? "" : agent.getBatiment();
        csv += agent.getNom() + ";" + agent.getPrenom() + ";" + organisation + ";" + agent.getOrganisation().getIdUnite() + ";"
                + batiment + ";"
                + ("1".equals(agent.getStatut_agent()) ? "Oui" : "Non") + "\n";
    }

    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(csv.getBytes());
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    return mapping.findForward("exporter");
}
```

I tried to display the encoding of the csv downloaded and I noted a difference between local/server:

- CSV from local: `file dev.csv -- Output : ISO-8859 text` - No encoding problems
- CSV from server: `file server.csv -- Output : Unicode text, UTF-8 text` - Encoding problems

Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: You should be using a `Writer` not the raw output stream with UTF-8 as the encoding and that as the response charset

Comment: `try (Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            out.write(csv);
        }
`

Comment: I tried your code and adapt it and it works now! I had to change the charset from UTF-8 to ISO-8859, thanks a lot @g00se

Comment: *I had to change the charset from UTF-8 to ISO-8859* Why so?

Comment: I guess it's the encoding supported by my application, the issue i get appears when the  downloaded file was encoded with UTF-8 charset

Comment: Just seems strange these days to find 'something' won't read a file encoded as UTF-8

Comment: Yes i agree, but it's a very old application (+20 years...) so i guess it's wasn't the same encoding standard at this time